# recovering the argument of a sinusoidal function in matlab

Tags: matlab, arguments, unwrap

I have an experimental measurement that looks like as a sinusoid such that the function can be modelled as `sin(x)`. If I apply the `asin` function to the data I get a triangle function. I would like to know if there is a form to get the straight line corresponding to x in a way as unwrap does.
Any opinion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`unwrap` only works with sawtooth patterns, where the function jumps. So my idea would be to create such a sawtooth pattern from your function and then apply unwrap.

```
%example function
x=0:.1:10;
y=sin(x);
%invert
x1=asin(y);
%detect rising and falling
s=[true,diff(x1)>0];
%continue falling segments rising, using the negative slope
x2=x1.*s+(pi-x1).*(1-s);
%finally use unwrap
x3=unwrap(x2);

%code for the plot
%plot(x,y,x,x1,x,s,x,x2)
%legend({'y','x1','s','x2'})
```

[image]

Comment: @CarolinaRickenstorff Consider accepting the answer if it fulfills your needs (and the same applies to your previous questions)